# Подпись загруженного APK недействительна

Tags: android, google-play-console

При загрузке приложения в **Google Play Console** получаю ошибку, что *"подпись загруженного APK недействительна"*, но я вроде все по инструкции делал, хранилище ключей создал, выбирал **jar** и **apk** сигнатуры по отдельности и вместе, но в любом случае, выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите статью на русском http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php, может понятнее будет. Или опишите в вопросе как собирали релиз для маркета и свои действия в консоли.

Comment: Как раз по вот этому сайту и делал. Забыл упомянуть что некогда было загружено другое приложение и ключи от него утрачены. Но как я понял, для каждого приложения свои ключи.. Создал апк. Захожу в консоль, новое приложение, обзываю его, потом добавить апк в боковой панели, закрытый бета тест, соглашение о хранении ключей и принимал и нет, и вот собственно выберите файл и при загрузке такая ошибка

Comment: Либо ключи не те (не подходят по требованиям), либо не тот APK грузите. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне известно, вам нужно подписать полученный APK через команду:

```
apksigner sign --ks apk-release-key.jks --out app-release.apk app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Где:

`apk-release-key.jks` - ваш ключ, который нужен для подписи

`app-unsigned-aligned.apk` - ваше приложение неподписанное

`app-release.apk` - на выходе получите подписанный апк

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот это помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новое приложение в **Google Play Console**, при этом обязательно создайте уникальное имя пакета в проекте в Android Studio *(package name)*, для теста можете создать новый пустой проект, можете подписывать тем же ключом, но обязательно отметьте обе галочки **Signature Versions V1 и V2**. В **Google Play Console**, перед загрузкой, отклоните предложение Google хранить ключ у себя. Пробуйте загрузить Apk.